# JCR / Jackrabbit: hasNodes of type

Tags: java, jackrabbit, jcr

I need some sort of `hasNodes` **of type** method on the `Node` class. However, I am not sure how to accomplish this. I cannot iterate over the children as I am lazy loading - I fetch the children of the requested type with a query.

Has anybody got a good solution for that? Do I need to have another query for that, too?

Comment: Why can't you use a query that combines the two conditions: path starts with the path of the current node and node type is the one you're looking for?

Comment: That's what I already do but I fetch two types and want to avoid two roundtrips.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `getObejct(Path nodePath)` of the *Jackrabbit OCM* ([Object Content Mapping](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/object-content-manager.html)) to retrieve the object which creates a proxy and assigns it to the lazy loaded collection.